# I can't retrieve data from sqlite db using Ormlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

My model has a `java.sql.Date` variable and I am able to save just fine.

But whenever I try to retrieve  a row it throws this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field model.date_time_created has type
    java.sql.Date, got java.util.Date
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:557)
        at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignField(FieldType.java:576)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:71)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:202)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:118)
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:241)
```

My method to get a list :

```
public List<Model> getModelList() {
    try {
        return getHelper().getModelDao().queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Timber.e(ErrorUtils.getExceptionString(e));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Model is a placeholder

Comment: @John Ernest Guadalupe : check field model.date_time_created and import statement for Date type. It should have 'java.util.Date'..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IllegalArgumentException: field model.date_time_created has type java.sql.Date, got java.util.Date

The problem turned out to be a bug in `ORMLite`.  Under Android/SQLite we have to convert all dates to be strings and the conversion from `java.sql.Date` was broken.  Switching to `java.util.Date` will work.

This will be fixed in version 5.0.  See: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/51

Comment: Thank you. I also managed to fix this by switching to java.util.Date and changing the DataType in the annotation to DataType.Date

Comment: You shouldn't need the `DataType` since ORMLite will set that for you if you are using `java.util.Date` @JohnErnestGuadalupe.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is specifying `java.sql.Date`, but your Ormlite field is of type `java.util.Date`. The solution is to change the import at the top of your java file so that the correct class is brought in.

Comment: Will this work? I remember I switched to java.sql.Datw because java.util.Date is not compatible